# The accordion is not expanding on click. What may be the issue?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have used jQuery and bootstrap to develop this.
I have used bootstrap collapse(accordion), carousel, and cards.
When I click on the button, class "collapse show" is added to the div, but it is not displaying any content. When I click again class "collapsed" also gets added. But the whole thing is not working.

Here is my code.

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0"
    />
    <title>Crio News Feed</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Crio Feed Website" />
    <!-- bootstrap link -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <!-- Google fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@600&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!-- Font Awesome link -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <!-- CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/index.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="rect"></div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-4">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Crio News Feed</a>
      </nav>
      <hr />

      <div>
        <p class="today">Today</p>
        <p class="content">The insights you need to keep ahead</p>
      </div>

      <div id="accordion">
       
      </div>
      
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>

    <script src="resources/data/magazines.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
let ID = () => Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);

let accordianDiv = (title, id) =>
  $(`
    <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="head btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#${id}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="${id}">
          <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i> ${title}
          </button>
        </h5>
        <div id="${id}" class="collapse show" data-parent="#accordion"></div>
    `);

let carouselDiv = (id, innerID) =>
  $(`

<div id="${id}" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div id="${innerID}" class="carousel-inner">
  
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#${id}" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#${id}" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
`);

let carouselItemDiv = (id, active) =>
  $(`

<div id="${id}" class="carousel-item" ${active ? "active" : ""}>
    </div>
`);

let cardDiv = (item) =>
  $(`<div class="card d-block style="width: 18rem;">
<img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="${item.enclosure.link}" >
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">${item.title}</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">${item.author}</h6>
    <p class="card-subtitle text-secondary">${item.pubDate}</p>
    <p class="card-text">${item.description}</p>
    <a href="${item.link}" class="stretched-link"></a>
  </div>
</div>
`);

for (i in magazines) {
  fetch(
    "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=" + encodeURI(magazines[i])
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      let accordianID = ID();
      let accordian = accordianDiv(data.feed.title, accordianID);
      $("#accordion").append(accordian);

      let carouselID = ID();
      let innerID = ID();
      let carouselShow = carouselDiv(carouselID, innerID);
      $(`#${accordianID}`).append(carouselShow);

      let items = data.items;
      for (j in items) {
        let card = cardDiv(items[j]);
        let carouselItemID = ID();
        let carouselItem = carouselItemDiv(carouselItemID, j === 0);
        $(`#${innerID}`).append(carouselItem);
        $(`#${carouselItemID}`).append(card);
      }
    });
}
```

CONSOLE
[browserConsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mu9h.png)

It is fetching urls from a different magazines.js file which has 3 links in it.

I am unable to find the issue. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Are any errors shown in the browser console?

Comment: @phuzi No errors in the console